# How to convert SQSevent to DynamodbEvent in Java

Tags: java, lambda

I have an AWS lambda function using DynamodbEvent as input.

I have another AWS lambda function using SQSEvent as input. And I would like to convert this SQSEvent to DynamodbEvent so that I can call my first lambda using InvokeRequest method.

I haven't found any direct solution yet. Seems like I have to build classes myself to do this. If you know any good way to convert SQSEvent to DynamodbEvent please let me know.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue. In case anyone found this useful.

I was thinking sending to queue using "objectMapper.writeValueAsString" and "objectMapper.readValue(item.toJSON(), DynamodbEvent.class)" to get the data.

The problem is that DynamodbEvent cannot be serialized since it's not a valid json. The work around is to directly call handler with DynamodbEvent as input instead of converting.